# An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, dllimport

I am using C# loading C++ dll, and got this error:

**"An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in MyApp.exe"
"Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8057000B)**

I could not figure out why. The C++ dll was generated using vs2012 wizard, win32 application, dll with pre-head. It is built with x64 option. Here is the code:

```
// MyNativeDLL.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
    //char* pMemoryBuffer = NULL;
    using namespace std;

    __declspec(dllexport) long  Test()
    {
        long a;
         a = 1;
         a++;
         return a;
    }
```

The C# code calling it is:

```
[DllImport("C:\\MyNativeDLL\\x64\\Debug\\MyNativeDLL.dll",  EntryPoint = "Test")]
private extern static int Test();
void doJob()
{
   long a = Test();  // exception thrown here
}
```

C# code is built with Any CPU option, and it is loading the x64 native dll.
I wondering where I did wrong? I have been trying long, but really get stuck here. Thanks!

**UPDATE**
When I compile my native dll using win 32 option, and set up correct dll path, it loads successfully. But when I compile my native dll with x64 options, load with correct path, the loading fails.

Comment: check if the process is 32 bit while the dll is 64 bit, or vs verse

Comment: why return type is kept `int`? What happens when you keep target platform as `x64` for your C# application?

Comment: It seems my application is 32 because it has a 32* in windows process monitor. But I create my application using C#, so how do I change it to x64?

Comment: @HassanNisar It throws same error.

Comment: @Ono, may be not relevant but can you please tell why using `private extern static int Test();` instead of `private extern static long Test();`?

Comment: @HassanNisar When I compile my native dll using win 32 option, and set up correct dll path, it loads successfully. But when I compile my native dll with x64 options, load with correct path, the loading fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned:
 *The C++ dll was generated using vs2012 wizard, win32 application, dll with pre-head. It is built with x64 option*

The DLL and exe have to be both 32 bit, or both 64 bit.

Comment: How do I make this happen? I thought for C#, just build with Any CPU? But that gives the error I mentioned in the thread.